# Empty list equals empty list

Tags: java

I have an empty list of Stings and also an empty list of Integers. It seems that these lists are equal in Java. I am curious why this is, because the lists only can contain elements of different objects.

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
boolean compareLists = strings.equals(ints);
```

Why is `compareLists` true in this case?

Comment: Generic types are erased at compile time and therefore absent at runtime

Comment: It is misleading that `List<String>` and `List<Integer>` are often called "a list of Strings" and "a list of Integers" respectively. They're both just Lists. The `<T>` is a directive to the compiler to insert a bunch of casts to type `T` in relevant places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the documentation of `AbstractList.equals(Object o)`:

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal.

You're passing an object which is a list, both lists have the same size (0 in this case) and all corresponding pairs of elements (there are none) are equal.

All conditions are met, so the method returns `true`

**EDIT:**
As @Smutje said, generic types are erased at compile time and therefore absent at runtime.
In other words, the 'type' of list is not relevant.

Comment: Especially the last part.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this)
        return true;
    if (!(o instanceof List))
        return false;

    ListIterator<E> e1 = listIterator();
    ListIterator<?> e2 = ((List<?>) o).listIterator();
    while (e1.hasNext() && e2.hasNext()) {
        E o1 = e1.next();
        Object o2 = e2.next();
        if (!(o1==null ? o2==null : o1.equals(o2)))
            return false;
    }
    return !(e1.hasNext() || e2.hasNext());
}
```

This is the code of equals for an ArrayList. Meaning if both lists are empty the last condition is evaluated, which results in true.

Comment: "Meaning if both lists are empty" Not just if they're empty: if they both contain all null elements (and are the same size), they're also equal.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are equal when they are of the same length and all elements (at their respective positions) are equal.

That is the case for all empty lists.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no data in any of the lists, the lists are the following:

```
strings: []

ints: []
```

So, the "comparelists" compares if [ ] is equal to [ ]. Which is true!

Hence the "comparelists" boolean in this case is true since they are equal. Once any of the lists gets a record, then the "comparelists" boolean is not equal anymore!